# Spring Mvc Option implementation

Tags: spring-mvc

From the site http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html,

I have known the option tag implementation in spring mvc looks likes as follows

```
<tr>
    <td>Country:</td>
    <td>
        <form:select path="country">
            <form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
            <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="name"/>
        </form:select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I have implemented this code as per my need as follows

```
<tr>
        <td>Country:</td>
        <td>
            <form:select path="minerals">
                <form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
                <form:options items="${mineralList}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="name"/>
            </form:select>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

here **mineralList** is list containing names of minerals and is returned by refereceData() method in Controller class.

My model class looks like as follows

```
class Stones{
String minerals;

public String getMinerals() {
    return minerals;
}
public void setMinerals(String minerals) {
    this.minerals = minerals;
}
}
```

When application is run,Exception is occured as

Invalid property 'code' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'code' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

what is the solution please advice me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this because you've told the tag to use the `name` property of each item in the list, when generating the `<option>` labels. But your list consists of Strings, which have no name property.

Just remove that from the tag, and you'll be fine, i.e.:

```
<form:select path="minerals" items="${mineralList}" />
```